# Dotnet Highchart with Jdash Dashboard

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, highcharts

I am using Dotnet Highchart with Jdash to implement dashboard for my project, After Adding new chart all charts in the dashboard disappear including the new one, If I refreshed the page they appear again. also if I changed the setting of any chart I got the same result, Although that all thing work well, no exceptions, the generated javascript code form Dotnet Highchart is the same one generated after refresh and after adding chart.

Any Idea about this issue?

Comment: Have you any errors in the console (browser developer tools?)

Comment: No errors, all thing executed well.

Comment: Im sorry, am not dotnet developer